# How to use list constructors (./2) in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to use list constructor in SWI-Prolog, but am getting 'dict' expected error.

For example,

```
.(a, []) == [a].

ERROR: Type error: `dict' expected, found `a' (an atom)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] throw(error(type_error(dict,a),_14808))
ERROR:   [10] '$type_error'(dict,a) at /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/boot/init.pl:3369
ERROR:    [9] '$dicts':'.'(a,[],_14874) at /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/boot/dicts.pl:46
ERROR:    [8] '<meta-call>'(user:(...,...)) <foreign>
ERROR:    [7] <user>
Exception: (9) '.'(a, [], _14200) ?
```

Could anyone help me configure this functionality?

Comment: Start it up with option  `--traditional`.

Comment: ... or use a version of SWI prior to [SWI7](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/SWI7_and_ISO) like [these](http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable?show=all).

Comment: docs: [this](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ext-list-motivation) and [this](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=is_list/1).

Answer (score 5):

SWI-Prolog 7.x uses a different list constructor, `'[|]'/2`, instead of the traditional `./2` Prolog constructor:

```
?- '[|]'(1,[]) == [1].
true.
```

The change was motivated to free `./2` for other uses, notably in *dict* terms, as hinted in the error message you got for your query.

Comment: @921Kiyo this should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use `|` in conventional notation,

```
?- X = '[|]'(1,[0]).
X = [1, 0].
```

can be write like this

```
?- X = [1|[0]].
X = [1, 0].
```