# How to make list constructors (e.g .(a,[]) == [a].) work in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am learning Prolog and .(a,[]) == [a]. should return true in SWI-Prolog, but it gives me an error saying

```
ERROR: Type error: `dict' expected, found `a' (an atom)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] throw(error(type_error(dict,a),_4020))
ERROR:   [10] '$type_error'(dict,a) at /Applications/SWI-
Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/boot/init.pl:3369
ERROR:    [9] '$dicts':'.'(a,[],_4086) at /Applications/SWI-
Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/boot/dicts.pl:46
ERROR:    [8] '<meta-call>'(user:(...,...)) <foreign>
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Start the SWI Prolog executable with the [`--traditional`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348509/how-to-use-list-constructors-2-in-swi-prolog#comment75699549_44348509) command line option (comment due to user:[false](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false)).

Then it works:

> ```
> 1 ?- .(a,[]) == [a].
> true.
>
> 2 ?- current_prolog_flag( traditional, X).
> X = true.
>
> 3 ?- set_prolog_flag( traditional, false).
> ERROR: set_prolog_flag/2: No permission to modify flag `traditional'
>
> 4 ?-
> ```

This is mentioned in the documentation [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=running-options) (see "traditional", near the bottom of the page).

As can be seen, attempting to change it from within the running SWI session, fails.

Comment: @false I don't know. :) I used to post interaction snippets as code once but then was told they are supposed to be formatted as block quotes.

Comment: Where have you seen such advice?

Comment: @false I don't remember exactly.